# How to determine the goal symbol when tokenize ECMAScript in lexical grammar

Tags: javascript, macros, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, ecmascript-2017

I'm writing a JS macro preprocessor, and refer to the ECMA-262 specification for some guide to parse js code.

I use the code parser to determine where to do macro replace in a standard/precise way, which will distinguish some environments like:

```
macro(); // valid
foo = /macro()/; // invalid
foo = `macro()`; // invalid
foo = `some text ${macro()}`; // valid
```

When handling the source code tokenizing procedure, I encountered something called the [*goal symbol*](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar). I made some effort to understand them with some articles from [V8 blog](https://v8.dev/blog/understanding-ecmascript-part-3) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45722082/13430452).

However, I still can't understand how to determine the *goal symbol* in a standard way, I searched the specification and didn't find anything about this.

Comment: Based on the question, you'd be much better off modifying an existing parser. There are some open-source, high-quality JavaScript parsers out there, such as the ones used by Babel and various bundlers. Writing this from scratch requires a fair bit of parsing knowledge.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I will check it out later, I want to learn to write parsers by myself, and reading other one's source code may be helpful :)